# MongoDB aggregation query not matching the structure that being defined

Tags: database, mongodb, go, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**I have a requirement in my project where I have to perform a DB operation for getting a particular type of a total number of users. What I am doing is that, filtered all the queries in a slice and passing that Silce to my DB function.**

**This is the code snippet from where I am calling the DB function**

```
 {

 filters =  []bson.D{
        {{Key: "Mykey", Value: myvalue}},
        {{Key: "Mykey", Value: myvalue}},
        {{Key: "Mykey", Value: myvalue}},
        {{Key: "Mykey", Value: myvalue}},

 counts, err := dbmain.NoOfDocumentsInfo(MyDBName, myCollectionName, filters...)
 
 }
```

**Below is my called function**

```
 func NoOfDocumentsInfo(DB string, col string, filters ...bson.D) ([]int64, error) {
if nil == dbInstance {
  if nil == GetDBInstance() {
    logger.Error("Not connecting to DB")
    err := errors.New("DB connection error")
    return nil, err
  }
    }

logger.Debugf("%s %s", DB, col)

coll := dbInstance.Database(DB).Collection(col)

counts := make([]int64, len(filters))
for i, filter := range filters {
  count, err := coll.CountDocuments(context.TODO(), filter)
  if err != nil {
    logger.Fatal(err)
    return nil, err
  }

  counts[i] = count
}

return counts, nil
}
```

**As you can see I am calling the "coll.CountDocuments" functions multiple times. What I want is to write the code without calling the "coll.CountDocuments" function multiple times by aggregating all the filters into a single query.**

**I have tried to use the aggregation pipeline but my "cur" and "result" is giving null output. If you run the code you will be able to see it.**

```
func NoOfDocumentsInfo(DB string, col string, filters ...bson.D) ([]int64, error) {
if dbInstance == nil {
  if GetDBInstance() == nil {
    logger.Error("Not connecting to DB")
    err := errors.New("DB connection error")
    return nil, err
  }
}

logger.Debugf("%s %s", DB, col)

coll := dbInstance.Database(DB).Collection(col)

pipeline := make([]bson.M, 0, len(filters)+2)
pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"$or": filters}})
pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{"$group": bson.M{"_id": nil, "count": bson.M{"$sum": 1}}})
pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{"$group": bson.M{"_id": nil, "count": bson.M{"$first": "$count"}}})

var result struct {
  Count int64 `bson:"count"`
}

cur, err := coll.Aggregate(context.TODO(), pipeline)
if err != nil {
  logger.Fatal(err)
  return nil, err
}

logger.Debugf("cur: %+v", cur)
err = cur.Decode(&result)
logger.Debugf("result: %+v, err: %v", result, err)
if err != nil {
logger.Fatal(err)
return nil, err
}

return []int64{result.Count}, nil
}
```

Comment: Please format your question properly

Comment: Take a look at $facet, but remember it is not using indices, so try to use `match` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a field for each filter in `$group`, you may use `$cond` to conditionally increment the given counter. But this may very well end up not using indices, and thus being even slower than the separate, original count queries. Also note that using `$or` may also result in skipping indices. Also note that in `$cond` you may have to transform filters (e.g. add `$` to field names).

You'd better launch concurrent count queries (using `go`) for each filter, and if they are indexed, they will complete fast. This is how it could look like:

```
func docCounts(db string, col string, filters ...bson.D) ([]int64, error) {
    // ... obtain collection
    coll := dbInstance.Database(db).Collection(col)

    counts := make([]int64, len(filters))
    errs := make([]error, len(filters))

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(len(filters))

    for i := range filters {
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            counts[i], errs[i] = coll.CountDocuments(context.TODO(), filters[i])
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    // Produce some kind of error if any of the queries failed.
    var err error
    for _, e := range errs {
        if e != nil {
            err = fmt.Errorf("at least one query failed: %w", e)
            break
        }
    }
    // Note: starting with Go 1.20, you could simply write:
    // err = errors.Join(errs)

    return counts, err
}
```

Comment: @JoytiprokashRoy Yes, as mentioned in the beginning of my answer, but that will likely result in an operation that won't be able to use indices, and if you have many documents in your database, it will be slower.

Comment: Is there any way we could accomplish the task without "loop"?

 If you see my "NoOfDocumentsInfo" function, what I am doing is that calling the 
'coll.CountDocuments' multiples times. What I wanted to do now is avoid multiple 'coll.CountDocuments' calls without using "for loop" 

coll := dbInstance.Database(DB).Collection(col)

counts := make([]int64, len(filters))
for i, filter := range filters {
  count, err := coll.CountDocuments(context.TODO(), filter)
  if err != nil {
    logger.Fatal(err)
    return nil, err
  }

  counts[i] = count
}

Comment: @JoytiprokashRoy Yes, I understand what you want, and what I'm telling is that if you get rid of the loop, `NoOfDocumentsInfo()` will be slower.